# Test against actual value of input type="number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, numbers

I am creating a form for a mobile web app with input boxes asking for number input, so I'm using `input type="number"` for the validation and it's working well. I am also changing behavior based on the input in the box. I need to hide a `div` until the user enters text in the box. When they delete all text from the box, then hide the `div` again. This is easy to do - detect `keyup` on the input and if its `value` is an empty string or not. The problem comes when the user enters text that's not a valid number (possible, at least with iOS keyboard). The `value` of the input box is an empty string when the entered text is not a valid number, unfortunately. So my code is hiding the `div` when I do still need it to be visible, because it thinks the input box has no `value` in it.

How can I get the actual `value` stored in a number input type so I can test against it? (I need to keep it a number input type so the proper keyboard appears.) Thanks!

Here's my snippet of code:

```
$('input.deletable').keyup(function() {
     console.log($(document.activeElement).val()); //returns empty string if input is "?)&" for example
     if ($(document.activeElement).val() != '')
          $('#myDiv').css('display', 'block');
     else
          $('#myDiv').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: The empty string really *is* the "actual value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that "document.activeElement" isnt the best way to get the current input value. You can verify the input validity as well.

```
$('input.deletable').keyup(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     if ($this.val() != '' && this.checkValidity())
          $('#myDiv').css('display', 'block');
     else
          $('#myDiv').css('display', 'none');
});
```